# How to decrease time of loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, loops

I have a database table with about 4,000 names. I need to read those in, cycle through them and create entries in another table with those names along with id's the user enters. There could be up to 20 id's. I've written this code but if was still running after three minuets so I stopped it. I'm hoping there is a way to code it to reduce that time. It will be on a shared server with a max execution time of 60 seconds so it can't take any longer than that. Here's what I have. Can anyone see a way to increase the speed?

```
    $mysql_query = "select id from main_table";
    $post = array('0' => 1, '1' => 2); //up to 20 entries
    $cnt = count($post);
    $str = '';

    while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_query)) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; ++$i)  {
        $str .= "('" . $item['id'] . "', '" . $post[$i] . "'),";
      }    
    }  
    $str = substr($str, 0 -1);
    mysql_query("insert into next_table values" . $str );
```

Comment: Why not do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM?` Let the database do all the work in a single query.... you should be able to inject your new IDs into that

Comment: You can not run a fetch loop on the query string. You need to do a mysql_query() first. Probably why it takes so long.

Comment: Won't mysql_fetch_array always return false as you're not running the query first? So the loop will run forever

Comment: Yes, it should display an error. But nevertheless the code he is posting is not correct.

Comment: Do _not_ use the `mysql_*` interface; switch to either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution that does not require PHP loop and string concatenation at all. But you still need PHP code (left as exercise) to convert this:

```
$post = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Into this:

```sql
SELECT 1 AS val UNION ALL
SELECT 2        UNION ALL
SELECT 3
```

And this is the one query you need to execute:

```sql
INSERT INTO next_table
SELECT main_table.id, userval.val
FROM main_table
JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 2        UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
) AS userval
```

Spoiler:

> ```
> $post = array(1, 2, 3);
> $sql = array_reduce($post, function($acc, $value){
>   $cur = $acc === "" ?
>     sprintf("SELECT %d AS val", $value) :
>     sprintf("\nUNION ALL SELECT %d", $value);
>   return $acc . $cur;
> }, "");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you will not find other solution how to decrease the time of execution time, ie. any kind of optimization then you can try to *decrease the number of record being processed at once*.

Do block of amount of id's that can be processed within the time execution limit.

```
// get the very last inserted record from next_table
// and select reasonable amount of records from main_table to process
$mysql_query = "SELECT id FROM main_table 
WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM next_table MAX(id) LIMIT 1) 
LIMIT 500)"; // change the 500 to whatever
```

Then call the script as many times as there are any data waiting to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code based on the answer by Salman A. It takes about 3 seconds to complete. Excellent. I'm posting the new code in case someone needs it at some point.

```
    $mysql_query = mysql_query("select id from main_table");
    $post = array('0' => 1, '1' => 2); //up to 20 entries
    $cnt = count($post);
    $str = '';

    if ($cnt == 1) {
        $str .= "SELECT " . $post[0] . " AS val ";
    } else {    
        $str .= "SELECT " . $post[0] .  " AS val UNION ALL ";

        for ($i = 1; $i < $cnt; ++$i) {              
            $str .= " SELECT " . $post[$i] . " UNION ALL ";
        }
        $str = substr($str, 0, -11);
    }

    $raw = "INSERT INTO next_table SELECT main_table.id, userval.val
      FROM main_table JOIN ( " . $str . " ) AS userval ";             

    mysql_query($raw);
```